# Starting from which version Gradle supports Java 17

Tags: java, gradle, java-17

When trying to configure the project I'm getting the error:

> Unsupported Java. Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.1 and Gradle 7.0.

Unfortunately there are no information in [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) for now.

Comment: You'd have better luck searching github issues - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18508

Comment: thanks! following your link I have found another issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16857 according to which the answer is version 7.2.

Comment: I'm using Gradle 7.2 with JAVA 17 and IntelliJ 2021.2.3 without problems.

Comment: I am also using the same setting (Gradle 7.2, Java 17, and IntelliJ 2021.2.3), and it works well.

Comment: Gradle 7.2 *may* work with Java 17 but it is not officially supported. Eg. I had problems when using Kotlin with Java 17 and Gradle versions <7.3 .
Based on the official compatibility table, Gradle 7.3 is the first version supporting Java 17.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Gradle 7.3 is the first version fully supporting Java 17. From the [Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/release-notes.html#java17):

> **Support for Java 17**
>
> Gradle now supports running on and building with Java 17.
>
> In previous Gradle versions, running Gradle itself on Java 17 resulted in an error. JVM projects could have been built with Java 17 [using toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/userguide/toolchains.html).
>
> As of Gradle 7.3, both running Gradle itself and building JVM projects with Java 17 is fully supported.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the Gradle and Java version compatibility.

For gradle 7.0 , you have to downgrade to Java 16.

Or you keep Java 17.0.1 , your gradle has to be update to 7.3 or above.

### Table Java compatibility

| Java version | First Gradle version to support it |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 2.0 |
| 9 | 4.3 |
| 10 | 4.7 |
| 11 | 5.0 |
| 12 | 5.4 |
| 13 | 6.0 |
| 14 | 6.3 |
| 15 | 6.7 |
| 16 | 7.0 |
| 17 | 7.3 |
| 18 | 7.5 |
| 19 | 7.6 |
| 20 | 8.1 ⚠ |

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Answer (score 4):

From version 7.3 Gradle is officially supporting Java 17. For more details, compatibility matrix can be seen [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java) and details of releases can be seen from [here](https://gradle.org/releases/).

Comment: HI @Deepanshu Bhardwaj ! please follow the practice of being specific to question what will help community members and to upvote and accept your answer. As we can see question states that "from which version Gradle supports Java 17". Thanks

Comment: Edited my response :) @NotABot