# Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map - gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

When i try build project, terminal return error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.18.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.kodilla'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.13'
}
```

PS D:\Development\Projects\project-jdp-2212-02> ./gradlew wrapper --stacktrace

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                       
* What went wrong:                                                                                                                                                                     
Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                       
* Try:                                                                                                                                                                                 
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                       
* Exception is:                                                                                                                                                                        
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map                                                                                    
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.getWindowsEnv(WrapperProcess.java:127)                                                                                  
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.setEnvInternal(WrapperProcess.java:100)                                                                                 
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.setEnvironmentVariable(WrapperProcess.java:85)                                                                          
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.setNativeEnvironmentVariable(NativePlatformBackedProcessEnvironment.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.setEnvironmentVariable(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:67)                              
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.processenvironment.AbstractProcessEnvironment.maybeSetEnvironment(AbstractProcessEnvironment.java:41)                                 
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:65)                                                                 
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)                                                                                   
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)                                                                       
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)                                                               
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)                                                                             
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.util.Map java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to 
unnamed module @5a39699c
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcess.getWindowsEnv(WrapperProcess.java:124)
        ... 16 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

```
Tried to find a solution in web but to no avail
```

Comment: Please execute two additional commands and add result output here:  
`./gradlew wrapper --stacktrace` and `./gradlew --version`

Comment: gradle verson - 4.10.2, and ./gradlew wrapper --stacktrace is too long and i can't add result in com

Comment: I added the result in "ask"

Comment: OK, but could you paste all info regarding the second command because JVM version is also important

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.2                                               
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-09-19 18:10:15 UTC
Revision:     b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          17.0.5 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.5+9-LTS-191)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: You are running Java version 17. To use Gradle with Java 17 you must upgrade to at least Gradle 7.3 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801373/starting-from-which-version-gradle-supports-java-17). The alternate approach is to use an older Java version (Java 1.8 if you want to stay with Gradle 4.10, Java 11 if you can upgrade to Gradle 5.0 or later).

Comment: Btw, I found one nice article with great explanation and way of fix: https://highlysuspect.agency/posts/unable_to_get_windows_mutable_environment_variable_map/ . I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that based on what you wrote in the comments under your post I found the cause of the error.

Take a look at the Gradle version you are using and the JVM version - the time difference between them is quite large. In other words, they are incompatible.

[image]

Update gradle version or change JAVA_HOME path to older JVM version

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i realize its a compatibility problem. i'll mention the facts i knew about that. and what i did to solve the issue.

- VSCode seems to be very bad with building gradle.
- you have to open the project as an android project, in order to update the gradle using `Tools` > `AGP Upgrade Assistant`. In android Studio, close the current flutter project. open the android folder inside your flutter project.
- the first issue i noticed from the build results that im using a java version in my project different from the JDK i installed and set the `JAVA_HOME` env variable to. i deleted the `JAVA_HOME` cos it seemed like the project already has a java instance (i honestly dont fully understand that up until this moment).
- your project uses a built in gradle version located at `android` > `gradle` > `wrapper`. for some reason my project was failing to overrite that, so i manually deleted it. rebuilt the `build.gradle` with changing the gradle version to what i want.

> I know the answer isn't perfectly written. hopefully i'll come back to edit it later. i just hope it helps in the meanwhile.